# Порядок тестирования Pytest

Tags: python, flask, тестирование, pytest

Тестирую `flask app` с помощью `pytest`, который проходит тесты в порядке расположения директорий, т.е. у меня сначала расположена директория `func_tests`, потом `unit_tests`, в результате тесты падают, если поменять расположение директорий, т.е. `unit_tests` потом `func_tests`  тесты проходят. Либо я неправильно написал тесты, либо как-то надо в pytest определить порядок тестов, подскажите пжл.
Вот структура тестовых файлов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: "Либо я неправильно написал тесты" - видимо да. Успешность выполнения тестов не должно зависеть от порядка директорий. Но не зная, что там у вас тесты делают, ничего конкретного посоветовать нельзя.

Comment: нашел причину падения тестов, все тесты проходят, ошибка в самом коде, а не в тестах, спасибо